# Giving a derived table an alias produces an error

Tags: mysql, sql

If I run the following code I get 'every derived table must have its own alias' but if I try to include an alias at the end of `GROUP BY itemID)` with `AS Cust` or something, I get a syntax error. What's going on here?

```
SELECT * FROM(
(SELECT itemID, COUNT(itemID)
FROM Item
GROUP BY itemID) AS Head

LEFT OUTER JOIN(

SELECT * FROM(
SELECT itemID
FROM (Customer LEFT OUTER JOIN Bid ON custNum = buyerNum) LEFT OUTER JOIN Item USING (itemID)
WHERE custNum = 'pxtfj044'
GROUP BY itemID)) AS Now
```

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. Similarly, in the absence of any aggregating aggregating or LIMITing of the data set, a subquery is not normally useful. I suggest you start over, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You have too many parentheses and your `LEFT JOIN` needs an `ON` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT itemID, COUNT(itemID)
      FROM Item
      GROUP BY itemID
     ) Head LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT itemID
      FROM Customer LEFT OUTER JOIN
           Bid
           ON custNum = buyerNum LEFT OUTER JOIN
           Item
           USING (itemID)
      WHERE custNum = 'pxtfj044'
      GROUP BY itemID
     ) Now
     ON . . .
```